A Select Statemebt which runs in SQL doesn't run in PLSQL when I add the INTO part
So the select works when just SQL but when I go to transform it into PL/SQL I get a
NOT A GROUP BY FUNCTION... when clearly it is... I'm not sure what I'm missing....
thanks
DECLARE
 readdate VARCHAR(100);
 watts INT(5);
BEGIN
for i in REVERSE 1 .. 120
LOOP
SELECT
    to_char(reading_date, 'MON-YYYY'), round(AVG(watts_reading), 2) into readdate,watts
FROM
    table 
WHERE
    to_char(reading_date, 'MON-YYYY') = to_char(add_months(sysdate,(1 * - 1)),'MON-YYYY') 
    group by to_char(reading_date, 'MON-YYYY');
END LOOP;
END;


but the the WATTS is an aggregate AVG

"NOT A GROUP BY FUNCTION" doesn't seem to make sense here. The query is valid. Well, you round your average to two decimal points only to read it into an integer then, but that is no error, just a flaw. The PL/SQL block works for me here without any errors: https://dbfiddle.uk/ivqSaZC0
